# Android Threads - Not working for me

Tags: java, android

I am working on a simple application with threads in Android. I have the following piece of code in my application. But this does not seem to be working.

```
l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
p = new LayoutParams(100, 100);
i = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb);
i.setLayoutParams(p);
i.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (running) {
        running = false;
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Log.d("INFO", "Thread executing");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
        }).start();
    }

    return false;
}
});
l.addView(i);
```

Even the log is not printing.

Edit: `running = false;` is before the code

Comment: it's because your code in the while condition is never reachable , because the variable `running` never setted to true ; try this : 
 `if (running) {
        running = false;
    } else {
       running = true;
       while(running) {...}`

Comment: @Houcine i have set running as false initially. this is inside my onCreate method

Comment: so if your running is false, the while will not be executed because you are testing on running == true ( `while (running)` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part with the logging is never reached. If `running` is true, it's set to false and the `else` branch is not executed. If it's false then the loop is never executed.

You should set `running` to `true` in the else branch. Also note that `running` should be `volatile` (if it's not already) to ensure that it's not cached locally for the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Running threads on main thread in android is very bad for performance in such low memory

check this Async Task which does the job parallely

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.de" });

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Your code here.          
    }
}
```